# I can't get left join result to view with pagination

Tags: linq

i can't pass the result to view, my Index view has pagination.

Index View:

```
@model rInventarioTI.Clases.PaginationList<rInventarioTI.Models.Productos>

@{
ViewData["Title"] = "Lista Productos";
}

<h1 class="text-center">Listado Productos</h1>

<br />
<br />
<br />

<form asp-action="Index" method="get">
<div class="form-group d-flex justify-content-center">
<p>
Tipo/Serie/Marca/Modelo
<input type="text" name="searchString" value="@ViewData["FiltroActual"]" />
<input type="submit" value="Filtrar" class="btn btn-primary" />
<a asp-action="Index">Borrar filtro</a>
</p>
</div>
</form>

<p class="float-end">
<a asp-action="Create" class="btn btn-success">Crear nuevo</a>
</p>

<table class="table">
<thead class="bg-dark" style="color: white;">
<tr>
<th>
    <a asp-action="Index" asp-route-sortOrder="@ViewData["TypeProductNameSortParm"]"
       asp-route-filtroActual="@ViewData["FiltroActual"]">Tipo de producto <i class="fas fa-sort-amount-down-alt"></i> </a>
</th>
<th>
    <a asp-action="Index" asp-route-sortOrder="@ViewData["COGSortParm"]"
       asp-route-filtroActual="@ViewData["FiltroActual"]">COG <i class="fas fa-sort-amount-down-alt"></i></a>
</th>
<th>
    <a asp-action="Index" asp-route-sortOrder="@ViewData["SerieSortParm"]"
       asp-route-filtroActual="@ViewData["FiltroActual"]">Numero de Serie <i class="fas fa-sort-amount-down-alt"></i></a>
</th>
<th>
    <a asp-action="Index" asp-route-sortOrder="@ViewData["MarcaSortParm"]"
       asp-route-filtroActual="@ViewData["FiltroActual"]">Marca <i class="fas fa-sort-amount-down-alt"></i></a>
</th>
<th>
    <a asp-action="Index" asp-route-sortOrder="@ViewData["ModeloSortParm"]"
       asp-route-filtroActual="@ViewData["FiltroActual"]">Modelo Equipo<i class="fas fa-sort-amount-down-alt"></i></a>
</th>
<th>
    @*@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.TiposMovimientosNav)*@
    Movimiento
</th>
<th>
    <a asp-action="Index" asp-route-sortOrder="@ViewData["DateSortParm"]"
       asp-route-filtroActual="@ViewData["FiltroActual"]">Fecha Registro<i class="fas fa-sort-amount-down-alt"></i></a>
</th>
<th>Operaciones</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
@foreach (var item in Model) {
<tr>
<td>
    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.TiposProductosNav.Nombre)
</td>
<td>
    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.COG)
</td>
<td>
    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.NumeroSerie)
</td>
<td>
    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.MarcasNav.Nombre)
</td>
<td>
    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Modelo)
</td>
<td>
    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.MovimientosProductosNav)
</td>
<td>
    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FechaAlta)
</td>
<td>
    <a asp-action="Edit" asp-route-id="@item.Id"><i class="fas fa-pencil-alt"></i></a> |
    <a asp-action="Details" asp-route-id="@item.Id"><i class="fas fa-eye"></i></a> |
    
    <a asp-action="Delete" asp-route-id="@item.Id"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i></a> |
    <a asp-action="Asignar" asp-route-id="@item.Id"><i class="fas fa-arrow-right"> Asignar</i></a> |
    <a asp-action="Desasignar" asp-route-id="@item.Id"><i class="fas fa-arrow-left"> Desasignar</i></a> |
    <a asp-action="Transferir" asp-route-id="@item.Id"><i class="fas fa-exchange-alt"> Transferir</i></a>
</td>
</tr>
}
</tbody>
</table>

@{ 
var prevDisabled = !Model.HasPreviousPage ? "disabled" : "";
var nextDisabled = !Model.HasNextPage ? "disabled" : "";
}

<a asp-action="Index"
asp-route-sortOrder="@ViewData["OrdenamientoActual"]"
asp-route-pageNumber="@(Model.PageIndex + 1)"
asp-route-filtroActual="@ViewData["FiltroActual"]"
class="btn btn-primary @nextDisabled float-end">Adelante</a>

<a asp-action="Index"
asp-route-sortOrder="@ViewData["OrdenamientoActual"]"
asp-route-pageNumber="@(Model.PageIndex - 1)"
asp-route-filtroActual="@ViewData["FiltroActual"]"
class="btn btn-primary @prevDisabled float-end">Atrás</a>
```

---

PaginationList

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace rInventarioTI.Clases
{
public class PaginationList<T> : List<T>
{
    public int PageIndex { get; private set; }
    public int TotalPages { get; private set; }

    public PaginationList(List<T> items, int count, int pageIndex, int pageSize)
    {
        PageIndex = pageIndex;
        TotalPages = (int)Math.Ceiling(count / (double)pageSize);
        this.AddRange(items);
    }

    public bool HasPreviousPage
    {
        get
        {
            return (PageIndex > 1);
        }
    }

    public bool HasNextPage
    {
        get
        {
            return (PageIndex < TotalPages);
        }
    }

    public static async Task<PaginationList<T>> CreateAsync(IQueryable<T> source, int pageIndex, int pageSize)
    {
        var count = await source.CountAsync();
        var items = await source.Skip((pageIndex - 1) * pageSize).Take(pageSize).ToListAsync();
        return new PaginationList<T>(items, count, pageIndex, pageSize);
    }
}
}
```

Productos Model:

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace rInventarioTI.Models
{
//[Index(nameof(COG), IsUnique = true)]
public partial class Productos
{
    public Productos()
    {
        MovimientosProductosNav = new HashSet<MovimientosProductos>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Tipo de producto")]
    //[Required(ErrorMessage = "Seleccione un tipo de producto")]
    public int TiposProductosID { get; set; }        

    [Display(Name = "Marca")]        
    public int MarcasID { get; set; }

    // Algunos productos pueden no tener numero de serie.
    [Display(Name = "Numero Serie")]        
    public string NumeroSerie { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Descripcion")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Ingrese una descripción")]
    [StringLength(1500, MinimumLength = 6, ErrorMessage = " Caracteres permitidos, mas de 6 y menos de 1500")]
    public string Descripcion { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Modelo del producto")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Ingrese un modelo para este producto")]
    public string Modelo { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Color de producto")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Ingrese un color para este producto")]
    public string Color { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Codigo del fabricante")]        
    public string CodigoFabricante { get; set; }

    // Clave unica e irrepetible. TODOS los productos deben tener
    // un COD definido y asignado por el sistema.
    [Display(Name = "COG")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Ingrese un COG")]
    [StringLength(25, MinimumLength = 3, ErrorMessage = "Ingrese un COG de entre 3 y 25 caracteres")]
    public string COG { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Datos QR del producto")]
    public string CodigoQr { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Fecha de Registro")]
    public DateTime FechaAlta { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Tipo de producto")]
    public virtual TiposProductos TiposProductosNav { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Marcas")]
    public virtual Marcas MarcasNav { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<MovimientosProductos> MovimientosProductosNav { get; set; }
}
}
```

MovimientosProductos Model

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace rInventarioTI.Models
{
public partial class MovimientosProductos
{
    public MovimientosProductos() { 

    }

    public int id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int ProductosID { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Tipo Movimiento")]
    [Required]        
    public int TiposMovimientosID { get; set; }


    [Display(Name = "Usuario Genera Movimiento")]
    public int UsuariosID { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Oficina Destino")]
    public int OficinasID { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Estado físico del producto")]
    public int EstadosProductosID { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Observaciones del movimiento y/o producto")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Observaciones del movimiento y/o producto")]
    [StringLength(1500, MinimumLength = 6, ErrorMessage = "Minimo 6 caracteres, maximo 1500 caracteres.")]
    public string Observaciones { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Fotos del producto")]
    public string PathFotos { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Fecha de Registro")]
    public DateTime FechaAlta { get; set; }        

    [Display(Name = "Produco")]
    public virtual Productos ProductosNav { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Tipo Movimiento")]
    public virtual TiposMovimientos TiposMovimientosNav { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Usuario generó movimiento")]
    public virtual Usuarios UsuariosNav { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Oficina asignada")]
    public virtual Oficinas OficinaNav { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Estado del producto")]
    public virtual EstadosProductos EstadosProductosNav { get; set; }


}
}
```

Productos Controller

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using rInventarioTI.Models;
using rInventarioTI.Clases;
using System.Collections.Generic;
//using System.Data.Entity;

namespace rInventarioTI.Controllers
{
public class ProductosController : Controller
{
private readonly rInventarioContext _context;

public ProductosController(rInventarioContext context)
{
    _context = context;
}

// GET: Productos
public async Task<IActionResult> Index(
    string sortOrder,
    string filtroActual,
    string searchString,
    int? pageNumber)
{
    ViewData["OrdenamientoActual"] = sortOrder;
    ViewData["TypeProductNameSortParm"] = String.IsNullOrEmpty(sortOrder) ? "Name_desc" : "";
    ViewData["COGSortParm"] = sortOrder == "COG" ? "COG_desc" : "COG";
    ViewData["SerieSortParm"] = sortOrder == "Serie" ? "Serie_desc" : "Serie";
    ViewData["MarcaSortParm"] = sortOrder == "Marca" ? "Marca_desc" : "Marca";
    ViewData["ModeloSortParm"] = sortOrder == "Modelo" ? "Modelo_desc" : "Modelo";
    ViewData["DatesortParm"] = sortOrder == "Date" ? "Date_desc" : "Date";

    // Valido si hay cadena de búsqueda ingresada
    if (searchString != null)
    {
        pageNumber = 1;                
    } else
    {
        searchString = filtroActual;
    }

    ViewData["FiltroActual"] = searchString;

    //var productos = (from prod in _context.Productos
    //                 select prod)
    //                 .Include(m => m.MarcasNav).AsQueryable()
    //                 .Include(t => t.TiposProductosNav).AsQueryable()
    //                 .Include(ep => ep.MovimientosProductosNav).AsQueryable();

    /*
     Recupera listado de productos, donde el numero de movimientos sea de 2 o mas.
     */
    var productos = (from prod in _context.Productos.ToList()
                     join mov in _context.MovimientosProductos on prod.Id equals mov.ProductosID into ProductosMovimientosGroup
                     from mov in ProductosMovimientosGroup.DefaultIfEmpty()
                     where (ProductosMovimientosGroup.Count() == 0)
                     select prod);



    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
    {
        productos = productos.Where(
            prod => prod.TiposProductosNav.Nombre.Contains(searchString) ||
            //prod.SerialesProductosID.
            prod.MarcasNav.Nombre.Contains(searchString) ||
            prod.Modelo.Contains(searchString) ||
            prod.COG.Contains(searchString));
    }

    switch (sortOrder)
    {
        case "Name_desc":
            productos = productos.OrderByDescending(prod => prod.TiposProductosNav.Nombre);
            break;
        case "COG":
            productos = productos.OrderBy(prod => prod.COG);
            break;
        case "COG_desc":
            productos = productos.OrderByDescending(prod => prod.COG);
            break;
        case "Serie":
            productos = productos.OrderBy(prod => prod.NumeroSerie);
            break;
        case "Serie_desc":
            productos = productos.OrderByDescending(prod => prod.NumeroSerie);
            break;
        case "Marca":
            productos = productos.OrderBy(prod => prod.MarcasNav.Nombre);
            break;
        case "Marca_desc":
            productos = productos.OrderByDescending(prod => prod.MarcasNav.Nombre);
            break;
        case "Modelo":
            productos = productos.OrderByDescending(prod => prod.Modelo);
            break;
        case "Modelo_desc":
            productos = productos.OrderBy(prod => prod.Modelo);
            break;
        case "Date":
            productos = productos.OrderBy(prod => prod.FechaAlta);
            break;
        case "Date_desc":
            productos = productos.OrderByDescending(prod => prod.FechaAlta);
            break;
        default:
            productos = productos.OrderBy(prod => prod.TiposProductosNav.Nombre);
            break;
    }

    int pageSize = 10;

    return View(await PaginationList<Productos>.CreateAsync(
        productos.AsNoTracking(),
        pageNumber ?? 1,
        pageSize));

    //return View(productos);
}

}
}
```

[Source: Tutorial: Add sorting, filtering, and paging - ASP.NET MVC with EF Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/sort-filter-page?view=aspnetcore-5.0)

My query in SQL works fine

[Image SQL Script works](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iDssv.jpg)

```
SELECT Productos.COG, Productos.Id
from Productos
left join MovimientosProductos on MovimientosProductos.ProductosID = Productos.Id
Group by Productos.Id, Productos.COG
having COUNT(MovimientosProductos.ProductosID) = 0
```

---

```
SELECT Productos.COG, Productos.Id, ProductosID
from MovimientosProductos
RIGHT join Productos on Productos.Id = MovimientosProductos.ProductosID
Group by Productos.COG, Productos.Id, ProductosID
having ProductosID IS NULL
```

My query in Linq is:

```
 var productos = (from prod in _context.Productos.ToList()
                         join mov in _context.MovimientosProductos on prod.Id equals mov.ProductosID into ProductosMovimientosGroup
                         from mov in ProductosMovimientosGroup.DefaultIfEmpty()
                         where ProductosMovimientosGroup.Count() == 0
                         select prod);
```

and in debug mode productos has 3 records. Works fine.

But when the app runs, i get this error:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
> Error CS1061  'IEnumerable' does not contain a definition
> for 'AsNoTracking' and no accessible extension method 'AsNoTracking'
> accepting a first argument of type 'IEnumerable' could be
> found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I understand that i need to get IQueryable result instead of IEnumerable, but how can i convert the result?

Then, i have removed ToList() from the query and AsNoTracking() from the return View for test, but now the error is:

> An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
> InvalidOperationException: The LINQ expression 'DbSet()
> .LeftJoin( inner: DbSet(), outerKeySelector: p
> => p.Id, innerKeySelector: m => m.ProductosID, resultSelector: (p, m) => new TransparentIdentifier<Productos, MovimientosProductos>( Outer = p, Inner = m )) .Where(ti => ProductosMovimientosGroup .Count() == 0)'
> could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can
> be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting
> a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or
> 'ToListAsync'. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for
> more information.

But i don't know how to translate the query...

Thank you

Comment: Remove `.ToList()` and query should work and `AsNoTracking` also. Also you have missed `GroupBy`.

Comment: Show your model. It is possible that you do not need JOIN at all.

Comment: thank you, i have changed to a navigation properties and i have resolved my initial problem. What i need to do with this post?

Comment: You may want to add the solution as an answer to your own question. It's OK to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your comments

Gert Arnold mentioned the navigation properties and then changed the query for this:

```
var productos = (from p in _context.Productos
                                .Include(mp => mp.MovimientosProductosNav)
                                .Include(m => m.MarcasNav)
                                .Include(tp => tp.TiposProductosNav).ToList()
                             select p);
```

I get the properties by "navigation properties" declared in my models and the view get model without any problem.

Now it works.

Comment: Please move this to your question, it's not an answer. In the mean time, why do you use `join` while you have navigation properties?